# How to get all comment authors of a single post?

Tags: comments

How I can get all comment authors from a single post?

I am building a plugin and want to notify the author of a post when someone comment on his post but if another person adds a comment I want to notify the author of the post and the authors of the other comments on that post.

I need the emails of the post author and all the comment authors from that specific post in a array do I can send them an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a loop and going through every comment is the option that I can offer you. Take a look at this example:

```
function get_comment_authors($post_ID){
    // Get every comment on this post
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post_ID
    );
    $comment_objects = get_comments( $args );
    // Define an empty array to store the comments
    $author_array = array();
    // Run a loop through every comment object
    foreach ( $comment_objects as $comment ) {
        // Get the comment's author
        $author_array[] = $comment->comment_author;
    }
    // Return the authors as an array
    return $author_array;
}
```

So, `get_comment_authors(123);` will return every author that left a comment on the post that has an ID of 123.

Comment: Hi small question, how to add also the post author email to the array? I tried this: `// get and add post author to array
            $author = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
            $author_mail = the_author_meta( 'user_email' , $author);
            $author_array[] = $author_mail;` but that doesn't work because the mail is not added to the array correctly. print_r gives this `mymail@me.comArray
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => info@mydomein.nl
)`

Comment: Already solved it, using get_the_author_meta instead of the_author_meta

Comment: @MaartenHeideman Hi! You can use `comment_author_email`, the email is already stored in the comments object. So you should use : `$author_array[] = array ($comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_email);` which will give you an array of name/email pairs, such as : `(john,john@example.com),(doe,doe@example.com)` and so on.